# Php global and show values

Tags: php, global

I need show this value in global var **global $f_[$id];**

**In function i have this string**

```
$f_[$id];
```

**$f_** it´s the string and value inside [] change and assign using the function and the finally values can show as this $f_[0] , $f_[34] , etc , the problem it´s i need something as this :

```
global $f_[$id];
```

And i know it´s incorrect writte but for understand me , because i need this value in a global var

I hope understand me , thank´s for the help

Regards

Comment: Which is the global variable, `$f_`, `$id`, or both?

Comment: Show the whole code, it's hard to tell what you're trying to do from this explanation.

Comment: `$GLOBALS['f_'][$id] = 'something';` maybe... Or `$GLOBALS['f_'] = $f_;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can only do

```
global $f_;
```

As the `[$id]` is an element of a variable, I am not aware you can only global 1 element.
If you want to ONLY pass `$f_[$id]` you could pass it as a reference

```
function dothis($value)
{  
   $value = '';//something new
}
dothis(&$f_[$id]);
```

and that will only the address for that single element.

Comment: Your reference example is wrong and will throw a syntax error. To pass it as a reference, the ampersand ( `&`) goes in the function definition: `function dothis(&$value)`, not in the call.